# Can't have my Microservices register in Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I have a Eureka server configured (It's workingas I can connect to it and see Eureka console) but my microservice won't register in it. I get a 403 server error (Forbidden). The authentication configuration in the Microservice trying to register seems OK as if I intentionally set it wrong, I get 401.

My gradle configuration:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
        gradleDockerVersion   = '1.2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.6.RELEASE"
        classpath("se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:${gradleDockerVersion}")
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.RELEASE'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}")
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix:2.0.1.RELEASE'
    }
}
```

This is my configuration. I have included it bith in bootstrap.yaml and in the configuration server just to make sure:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://myuserid:mypassword@localhost:8761/eureka/
```

But for some reason it's ignored. The root of that property is "eureka", not "spring.eureka..."?

Here is the error log in the Microservice, which seems to be trying localhost and standard port 8080, hence ignoring configuraton above.

```
2018-09-28 09:31:12.763  INFO 58552 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MTPMS_WEATHER/localhost:mtpms_weather:8080: registering service...
2018-09-28 09:31:12.767  INFO 58552 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2018-09-28 09:31:12.768  INFO 58552 --- [  restartedMain] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2018-09-28 09:31:12.803  WARN 58552 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failure with status code 403; retrying on another server if available
2018-09-28 09:31:12.808  WARN 58552 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MTPMS_WEATHER/localhost:mtpms_weather:8080 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found that there is a bug in current Eureka Server, described in this answer:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2754#issuecomment-372808529

So adding the following @EnableWebSecurity piece of code to the Gateway Spring Boot application server class fixes it:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class DiscoveryApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(DiscoveryApplication.class).run(args);
    }

    @EnableWebSecurity
    static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue, I was using the spring boot version 3.1.3, Below are my security config and application configurations

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return  http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers("/actuator/health/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
            )
        .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .csrf((AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable))
        .build();
}
```

In application.yml

`eureka: server: enableSelfPreservation: false client: register-with-eureka: true fetch-registry: false serviceUrl: defaultZone: http://admin:Qmic$123$@localhost:8761/eureka/ health: config: enabled: false server: port: 8761`

Give a thumbs if it helps somebody